# LINQ - GROUP BY on object to create string

Tags: c#, linq

So I have an object called Version

It contains a list of STATES, and a list of DATES

I want to first:

1. Group By the states, and create a string of all the states (comma separated)
2. Group BY the Dates, and create a string of all the dates (comma separated)

Here is what I have tried:

```
Date = Version.States.GroupBy(v => v.Date).Select(vh => vh.ToString()).ToString(),
State = Version.States.GroupBy(s => s.State).Select(st => st.ToString()).ToString()
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What are `STATES` and `DATES`, are these other classes?

Comment: This is States:

public virtual IList<VersionState> States
        {
            get { return _states; }
            set { _states = value; }
        }

Then States has this:

public virtual State State { get; set; }

        public virtual DateTimeOffset SDate { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var states = Version.States.Aggregate(string.Empty, (c, state) => c + state.ToString() + ",").TrimEnd(new []{','});
    var dates = Version.Dates.Aggregate(string.Empty, (c, date) => c + date.ToString() + ",").TrimEnd(new []{','});
```

Comment: but the .TrimEnd(new []{','}) still leave a comma at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `GroupBy`, you can use `Distinct` to get unique items which is more efficient. Then you can use `String.Join` to build the string:

```
var uniqueStates = Version.States.Select(vs => vs.State).Distinct();
var uniqueDates  = Version.Dates.Select(vd => vd.Date).Distinct();
string commaSeparatedStates = String.Join(",", uniqueStates);
string commaSeparatedDates  = String.Join(",", uniqueDates);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `string.Join` try this.

```
var Dates = string.Join(",",Version.States.GroupBy(v => v.Date).Select(vh => vh.ToString()));
var States = string.Join(",",Version.States.GroupBy(s => s.State).Select(st => st.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string all = string.Join( ","
                        , Version.States.GroupBy
                          ( s => s.State )
                          .Select(st => st.ToString())
                          )
                        );
```